# How to check errors log on heroku? (nodejs app)

Tags: node.js, logging, heroku, runtime

Where can I check what error my nodejs app is producing?
I dont have that error on my local machine, and heroku web worker only returns to browser:
`"Internal Server Error"`

How can I find out what is this error about?

Answer (score 2):

You can run `heroku logs` [command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) or use add-ons like [Papertrail](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail) to manage your logs.

If you error has an error code you can find more info about it in [Heroku Error Codes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes)